# LibGDX - get events for Stage and for Actors in this stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I have some Actors added to Stage. When I'm trying handle Actors tap events, pan function not working. Why? How to do it works?
This is summary of my problem.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter  implements GestureListener{

    static Grid grid;
    static Stage main_stage;
    static InputMultiplexer inputs;
    static GestureDetector gdect;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        main_stage = new Stage();
        inputs = new InputMultiplexer();
        grid = new Grid();
        grid.addToStage(main_stage);
        inputs.addProcessor(main_stage);
        dect = new GestureDetector(this);
        inputs.addProcessor(gdect);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        System.out.println("pan");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Grid.java

```
public class Grid {

    static Fields [] fields;

    void addToStage(Stage stage){
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        stage.addActor(fields[i]);
    }
}
```

Fields.java

```
public class Fields extends Actor {

    addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
        public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
            System.out.println("tap");
        }
    });
}
```